# What is the meaning of Wolverine's "I can put six shots into a quarter..." statement?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, wolverine-and-the-x-men

In the Weapon X comic, Wolverine says

> "I can put six shots into a quarter... an' get change for the
>   gum-machine."

What does he mean by that? I read it [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Howlett_%28Earth-616%29#Abilities).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't read the issue in question, but the explanation seems pretty straight-forward.  Shooting a hole in a quarter (that has been tossed into the air) is a common gunfighter trick in fiction; some even can shoot it more than once.  Many famous marksmen have claimed to do it; Annie Oakley being one of the better known ones.  Claiming to be able to do so (or some fancier version, as Wolvie does) is a common gunfighter's boast.

Six is a bit excessive, but from the same [Marvel Wiki article on him](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_%28James_%22Logan%22_Howlett%29) that you cite:

> Expert Marksman: He is an expert marksman skilled in throwing weapons and firearms, but operates more efficiently without them.

The comment about change for the gumball machine is a common piece of bravado added to such claims; it takes many forms.  He's talking about 'breaking' the quarter the same way you 'break' a dollar into change; he's just saying it to be silly/dramatic.

Comment: Oh Wolverine, you're so silly.

Comment: I want to sort of modify this answer by saying that the "change for a gumball machine" implies that he is *so* good, in fact, that the shots all pass through a relatively small hole in the center, leaving the outline and weight of the quarter mostly intact, which is what the gumball machine would check for validity.

Comment: The "change for a gumball machine" line refers to punching a nickel out of a quarter. Imagine trimming the outside edge of a quarter till it is the same size as a nickel.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, you kids today!  It's a meme, basically the same as [X all the Things!](http://memegenerator.net/X-All-The-Things) but older.

I would say that the "original" is, "Stop on a dime and give you change." but I can't find any cites for that.  There are many variations, just as there are with modern memes.

Saying that - for example - a car can "stop on a dime" is a boast about how good the car is.  A dime is about a centimeter in diameter (it's the smallest size of any US coin), so claiming that your car can stop in that short a distance is already a boast.  Adding the "give change" makes the boast stronger, by claiming that the car can stop in an even shorter distance.

Comment: sorry i didnt quite get that

Comment: I tried to clarify, but I guess it's more an answer for English Usage.SE...

Comment: -1 from me, that's not what Wolverine was saying at all. He meant the boast literally.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Logan is boasting of his accuracy with a pistol, of being able to place six shots in a diameter smaller than a US quarter-dollar coin.**

In marksmanship, the term "spread" refers to the distance between each bullet impact. Ideally, you want the smallest spread possible for the greatest precision & accuracy:

[image]

What Logan means when he says "I can put six shots into a quarter... an' get change for the gum-machine." is that he can shoot the quarter six times without nicking the edge - possibly even in the same place. Most [gumball machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumball_machine) of the era measured the diameter & edge of a coin to determine if it was a quarter or not. Therefore, a quarter full of holes would still work in the machine. Gumballs of the time were commonly only a nickel, so he would get his gumball plus two dimes back as change. The weight of the coin could be a factor too (depending on the machine), so this could also indicate placing bullets in almost exactly the same spot all six times (leaving only one hole in the coin).

[image]

**Note:** Coins have long been used to [show off precision with a firearm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhibition_shooting). The American sharpshooter [Annie Oakley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Oakley) was famous for her trick of flipping a dime into the air and shooting it with her pistol. Despite the similarity, however, that was a trick meant to show her accuracy with a moving target. Logan is instead boasting of his small target spread.